# Implementing from scratch cv2.warpPerspective()

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, homography

I was making some experimentations with the OpenCV function *cv2.warpPerspective* when I decided to code it from scratch to better understand its pipeline. Though I followed (hopefully) every theoretical step, it seems I am still missing something and I am struggling a lot to understand what. Could you please help me?

[SRC image (left) and True DST Image (right)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzZ2j.png)

[Output of the cv2.warpPerspective overlapped on the True DST](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQrBf.png)

```
# Invert the homography SRC->DST to DST->SRC
hinv = np.linalg.inv(h)
src = gray1
dst = np.zeros(gray2.shape)
h, w = src.shape

# Remap back and check the domain
for ox in range(h):
    for oy in range(w):

        # Backproject from DST to SRC
        xw, yw, w = hinv.dot(np.array([ox, oy, 1]).T)

        # cv2.INTER_NEAREST
        x, y = int(xw/w), int(yw/w)

        # Check if it falls in the src domain
        c1 = x >= 0 and y < h
        c2 = y >= 0 and y < w

        if c1 and c2:
            dst[x, y] = src[ox, oy]

cv2.imshow(dst + gray2//2)
```

[Output of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZ5gz.png)

PS: The output images are the overlapping of Estimated DST and the True DST to better highlight differences.

Comment: welcome. if you haven't already, please take the [tour].

Comment: What's the idea behind cv2.imshow(dst + src//2)? Do you really want to mix warped and not-warped image? Didnt you want to mix dst with true-warped?

Comment: I'd say that's blending, purely for visualization, to compare input and result. I would have recommended dividing both by 2 so the expected average brightness stays the same

Comment: In his comment he says "overlapping of Estimated DST and the True DST to better highlight differences" but he doesn't blend dst and true-dst but dst and src. So probably his test is just wrong.

Comment: a [mre] would have been nice. there are no values for the homography.

Comment: @Micka my bad. It was a typo. Now I edited the right cv2.imshow(). The output does not follow any blending purpose. I summed half of the ground truth simply to visualize it in the background and check how far my estimate is from the 'truth'.

Comment: I'm seeing the edits... `for ox in range(h)` that's gonna get you in trouble when your pictures aren't square... because x goes with w, not h, and y goes with h, not w. and now you've mixed up the indices in the assignment too. you want `dst[oy, ox] = src[iy, ix]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue amounts to a **typo**. You mixed up the naming of your coordinates. The homography assumes `(x,y,1)` order, which would correspond to `(j,i,1)`.

Just use `(x, y, 1)` in the calculation, and `(xw, yw, w)` in the result of that (then `x,y = xw/w, yw/w`). the `w` factor mirrors the math, when formulated properly.

Avoid indexing into `.shape`. The indices don't "speak". Just do `(height, width) = src.shape[:2]` and use those.

I'd recommend to fix the naming scheme, or define it up top in a comment. I'd recommend sticking with `x,y` instead of i,j,u,v, and then extend those with prefixes/suffixes for the space they're in ("src/dst/in/out"). Perhaps something like `ox,oy` for iterating, just `xw,yw,w` for the homography result, which turns into `x,y` via division, and `ix,iy` (*integerized*) for sampling in the *input*? Then you can use `dst[oy, ox] = src[iy, ix]`

Comment: Hey Chris, thank you for your suggestions. I think I am going to improve the namespace. I found your observation very useful and now it works! Thanks!